# How do I get my nav menu to open beneath the navigation bar and not inside of it?

Tags: javascript, html, css, nav, hamburger-menu

I'm attempting to implement a simple hamburger icon nav menu for a website I'm developing, but I'm having issues where the contents of the navigation menu are opening/appearing within the navigation menu and not below the nav bar.

HTML:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
    <head>
        <meta charset="utf-8">
        <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE-edge">
        <title>Buck's Farmstand</title>
        <link rel="icon" type="image/x-icon" href="G:\webDev\bucks_farmstand\images\tomatoFaviconRounded.ico">
        <meta name="description" content="">
        <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">

        <link rel="stylesheet" href="G:\webDev\bucks_farmstand\css\bucksMobileIndexStyles.css">
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/font-awesome/4.7.0/css/font-awesome.min.css">
    </head>

    <body id="mainPageBody">
        <header class="navHeader">
            <div class=buttonContainer>
                <a class="cta" href="G:\webDev\bucks_farmstand\html\bucksContact.html"><button>Contact</button></a>
            </div>
            <div class=logoContainer>
                <a href="#"><img class="logo" src="G:\webDev\bucks_farmstand\logos\newBucksLogo.jpg" alt="logo"></a>
            </div>
            <div id="myLinks">
                <a href="G:\webDev\bucks_farmstand\html\bucksInventory.html">Produce</a>
                    <a href="G:\webDev\bucks_farmstand\html\bucksPickUpComingSoon.html">Online-Order</a>
                <a href="G:\webDev\bucks_farmstand\html\bucksAbout.html">About</a>
                <a href="G:\webDev\bucks_farmstand\html\bucksContact.html">Contact</a>
            </div>
            <!-- "Hamburger menu" / "Bar icon" to toggle the navigation links -->
            <a href="javascript:void(0);" class="hamIcon" onclick="myFunction()">
                 <i class="fa fa-bars"></i>
            </a>
            
            <script>
            function myFunction() {
                var x = document.getElementById("myLinks");
                if (x.style.display === "block") {
                     x.style.display = "none";
                } else {
                        x.style.display = "block";
                }
            }
            </script>   
        
        </header>
            
        <br>    

    </body> 
</html>
```

CSS:

```
/*overrides everything for specifc page*/
* {
    box-sizing: border-box;
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
    /*background-color: #FFDAB9;*/
    overflow: auto;
    
    
}

/*referring to all of these categories not specifc to a class/ID*/
li, a, button {
    
    font-family: "cursive", cursive;
    font-weight: 500;
    font-size: 16px;
    color: #000000;
    text-decoration: none;

}



/*Bucks Nav CSS*/
/*Can add an href tag/ref here for logo to direct to*/
.logo{
    object-fit: cover;
    position: relative;
    height: 60px;
    width: 100%;
    cursor: pointer;    
}

.logoContainer{
    margin: auto;
    position: relative;
    right: 35px;
}

.navHeader{
    position: fixed;
    width: 100%;
    background: #deb887;
    display: flex;
    justify-content: space-between;
    align-items: center;
    padding: 2px 2%;
    height: 65px;
    overflow: hidden;

    z-index: 950;
}

.navHeader #myLinks{
    display: none;
    position: relative;
    top: 5px;
}

/* Style the hamburger menu */
.hamIcon {
  overflow: auto;
  background: none;
  display: block;
  position: fixed;
  right: 20px;
  top: 23px;
}


.cta{
    background: #deb887;
    overflow: hidden;
    width: 15%;
}

.buttonContainer{
    overflow: hidden;
}

button{
    padding: 9px 5px;
    background-color: rgba(35,255,0,0.5);
    border: 2px solid;
    border-radius: 50px;
    cursor: pointer;
    transition: all 0.3s ease 0s;
}

button:hover{
    background-color: yellow;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

The issue here is that your `<header>` class `.navHeader` is using `display: flex;` therefore items within that element will act as flex elements. You can read more about those [Here](https://css-tricks.com/almanac/properties/f/flex/)

There are a few ways you could go about this.

I think your best solution is to move the `<div id="myLinks"></div>` block below the header.

Then in your CSS: remove the `overflow: auto` from `*`.

Remove the class `.navHeader` before `#myLinks`, and add a few more properties to make sure the block is below your header `#myLinks{top: 65px; padding: 10px; text-align: center;}`

here is the full code:

HTML

```
<!DOCTYPE html>

<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE-edge">
  <title>Buck's Farmstand</title>
  <link rel="icon" type="image/x-icon" href="G:\webDev\bucks_farmstand\images\tomatoFaviconRounded.ico">
  <meta name="description" content="">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">

  <link rel="stylesheet" href="G:\webDev\bucks_farmstand\css\bucksMobileIndexStyles.css">
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/font-awesome/4.7.0/css/font-awesome.min.css">
</head>

<body id="mainPageBody">
  <header class="navHeader">
    <div class=buttonContainer>
      <a class="cta" href="G:\webDev\bucks_farmstand\html\bucksContact.html"><button>Contact</button></a>
    </div>
    <div class=logoContainer>
      <a href="#"><img class="logo" src="G:\webDev\bucks_farmstand\logos\newBucksLogo.jpg" alt="logo"></a>
    </div>
      <!-- "Hamburger menu" / "Bar icon" to toggle the navigation links -->
  <a href="javascript:void(0);" class="hamIcon" onclick="myFunction()">
    <i class="fa fa-bars"></i>
  </a>

  </header>
  <div id="myLinks">
    <a href="G:\webDev\bucks_farmstand\html\bucksInventory.html">Produce</a>
    <a href="G:\webDev\bucks_farmstand\html\bucksPickUpComingSoon.html">Online-Order</a>
    <a href="G:\webDev\bucks_farmstand\html\bucksAbout.html">About</a>
    <a href="G:\webDev\bucks_farmstand\html\bucksContact.html">Contact</a>
 
  </div>

  <br>
  <script>
    function myFunction() {
      var x = document.getElementById("myLinks");
      if (x.style.display === "block") {
        x.style.display = "none";
      } else {
        x.style.display = "block";
      }
    }
  </script>

</body>

</html>
```

CSS

```
/*overrides everything for specifc page*/
* {
  box-sizing: border-box;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  /*background-color: #FFDAB9;*/
  /*     overflow: auto; */
}

/*referring to all of these categories not specifc to a class/ID*/
li,
a,
button {
  font-family: "cursive", cursive;
  font-weight: 500;
  font-size: 16px;
  color: #000000;
  text-decoration: none;
}

/*Bucks Nav CSS*/
/*Can add an href tag/ref here for logo to direct to*/
.logo {
  object-fit: cover;
  position: relative;
  height: 60px;
  width: 100%;
  cursor: pointer;
}

.logoContainer {
  margin: auto;
  position: relative;
  right: 35px;
}

.navHeader {
  position: fixed;
  width: 100%;
  background: #deb887;
  display: flex;
  justify-content: space-between;
  align-items: center;
  padding: 2px 2%;
  height: 65px;
  overflow: hidden;

  z-index: 950;
}

#myLinks {
  display: none;
  position: relative;
  top: 65px;
  text-align: center;
  padding: 10px;
  width: 100%;
  background: #deb887;
}

/* Style the hamburger menu */
.hamIcon {
  overflow: auto;
  background: none;
  display: block;
  position: fixed;
  right: 20px;
  top: 23px;
}

.cta {
  background: #deb887;
  overflow: hidden;
  width: 15%;
}

.buttonContainer {
  overflow: hidden;
}

button {
  padding: 9px 5px;
  background-color: rgba(35, 255, 0, 0.5);
  border: 2px solid;
  border-radius: 50px;
  cursor: pointer;
  transition: all 0.3s ease 0s;
}

button:hover {
  background-color: yellow;
}
```